# Angular Js : $http.put absolute url doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a problem with $http.put of angular js : I have a server with node js and my app in angular js and I make some request with angular js to access to data on the node js server (same host).

This work:

```
$http.put("/fraisforfait", elements);
```

But this doesn't work : it does nothing..

```
$http.put("http://192.168.0.101:1337/fraisforfait", elements);
```

UPDATE : the error should be on server side ..

My server is on node js i have done this to setup CORS :

```
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin,    X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });
```

However nothing change ..

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

My test also fails with 192.168.x.x or 127.0.0.1 but with domain name it works fine.
Use

```
$http.put("http://localhost:1337/fraisforfait", elements);
```

or any other domain name.

Comment: it doesn't work for me : $http.put('http://localhost:1337/fraisforfait', elements); -> nothing

Comment: no this is just stackoverflow which transform it automatically as link

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely running into CORS, Cross Origin Resource Sharing. The end point you are accessing, http://192.168.0.101:1337/fraisforfait, will need to explicitly need add response headers telling your browser it is OK to access with anything other than GET or HEAD.

For development you can just have the server return: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in the response header. For production you will probably want to narrow this down -- or use relative paths.

[More Details on CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: I have already done it :         res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 28         res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
 29         res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Cache-Control");

Comment: Is your browser giving you any errors in the console?

Comment: moz : absolutely nothing chrome : XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.0.101:1337/fraisforfait. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

Comment: This means you do not have CORS configured correctly on your server.

Comment: I have setup it but nothing change